# Visual Studio Code tells me it can't import python module, yet it runs the code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, python-import

I am running a script in many folders and subfolders, the structure is kinda confusing but it basically is like:

```
src/
  controllers/
     __init__.py
     a.py
     b.py
   models/
     __init__.py
     c.py
   __init__.py
   main.py
```

The ^^^ is supposed to be the red error underline, main.py looks something like:

```py
from controllers import a
^^^^
import models.c
^^^^^^
```

a.py:

```py
import models.c
^^^^^^
```

I tried both, from and regular import, because maybe only one is bugged, but no, in VSC at every place I import like this, it tells me `unable to import [directory]` (it still runs from VSC and from the terminal via `python3 main.py`)

Things I tried

- Restarting VSC
- Rebooting my PC
- Changing stuff in `__init_.py` (yet nothing systematic, just playing around)

Is this a visual studio code issue, is it bad importing? Should I put stuff into `__init__.py`? Can I supress this issue or fix it somehow else?

Comment: I have the same problem. I have a program called `degrees.py` which imports another program called `util.py`, and VS Code throws an error for that too. But then it runs fine...

Comment: @Maritn Ge -Is "src" the parent folder of the file "main.py"?
According to the project structure you provided, the "main.py" file I tested has no _red error underline_.

Comment: @JillCheng yes, main.py is in src, a, b, and c are in the subdirectories. Were you using another environment? Maybe something else is broken

Comment: @Maritn Ge -Could you run the file "a.py"?

Comment: @JillCheng, the program runs, but it is just a constant error message

Comment: @M-Chen-3 I hope the solution below works for you too!

Comment: @MaritnGe Huh, for me the error just disappeared. Weird.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 lmao literally same i tried to undo the solution and it still randomly worked... very werid indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When importing modules in other folders, VSCode searches for files from the parent folder of the currently running file by default. For example: "`import models.c`" in "`a.py`", the parent folder "`controllers/`" of "`a.py`" does not have "`models`", so the terminal displays a warning.

When I removed the same level file "`__init__.py`" of "`main.py`", the terminal did not display errors and warnings:

[image]

For "`a.py`", I added the following settings in "`launch.json`", which adds the project folder path to the system path for VSCode to find:

```
"env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
```

Debug a.py:

[image]

Update:

On the premise that the code can run, I use the following settings to turn off the "[import-error](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md#import-error)" displayed by Pylint:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--disable=E0401"],
```

[image]